# use session is not expires , and user is not redirecting to Login page after idle time (MVC)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, cookies, session-state, expired-sessions

I'm not sure how to explain this problem. 
We have 3 environments (Dev,Staging, and Prod) .Project is written in MVC, code is the same in all .
webconfig setting for sessionstate timeout is the same as below :

```
<sessionState timeout="45" />
```

we have a partialView which is shown when browser is idle for 45 minutes

```
<div id="signoutDialog" data-role="dialog" data-close-btn="none">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="d">
        <h1 class="ui-title">Session Expired</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content" data-theme="a">
        <p>Looks like you’ve been away for a while! To keep your information safe, we’ve logged you out.</p>
        <p>To log back in, please click on the button below.</p>
        <p>
            <a data-role="button" data-rel="back" data-theme="b" data-corners="true" data-shadow="true" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="window.location.reload()" class="btn-green solid" id="btnSignoutDialogLogin">Log in</a>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Problem:** this code works fine in dev , but not in Staging and Prod. I checked the IIS settings in all . they're the same .
I'm not sure if any cookies should be chek , and how they can be related to this problem.

Any help would be appreciated .

**question : we have lots of background tasks run for user every few minutes . does it count as interaction ? does it renew session ID each time?**

Comment: It looks like serious problem ! Did you check version control history ??

Comment: @TaiwanHotDog I checked , no changes related to this.